# no exported names in the package "src/github.com/rohankeskar19/android_whisper"

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I'm trying to generate a binding for android from my go program but gomobile is giving me an error as

```
no exported names in the package "src/github.com/rohankeskar19/android_whisper"
```

This is the command I Used

```
gomobile bind -v -target=android -o ethereumchat.aar src\github.com\rohankeskar19\android_whisper\
```

**This is my folder structure**

```
bin
pkg
src
   |
    -github.com/
      |
       -rohankeskar19/
         |
          -android_whisper/
           |
            -ethereumchat.go
```

I know that in order to export names they have to start with capital letter

**This is my code**

```
package ethereumchat

import (
    "log"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/whisper/shhclient"
)


func Newkeypair(address string) string {
    client, err := shhclient.Dial(address)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "Error occured while connecting to whisper"
    }
    keyID, err := client.NewKeyPair(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return "Error occured while creating key pair"
    }

    return keyID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for you package as the folder in which it is located. (Your package is ethereumchat but the directory is andorid_whisper.)

Comment: This is what I'm getting along with no exported names in the package ```unable to import bind/java: go [-e -json -compiled=true -test=false -export=false -deps=false -find=true -- golang.org/x/mobile/bind/java]: exit status 2: go: finding golang.org/x/mobile latest
# runtime/cgo
gcc_android.c:6:25: fatal error: android/log.h: No such file or directory
 #include <android/log.h>```